# Pascal readkey seems to cause subseqent readln to ignore 1st character typed in response to readln. The readln only stores 2nd and later chars to var

Tags: pascal

I'm embarrassed to admit that I cannot understand why in this very simple example that the "readln(age);" statement in the "else if" clause ignores the first integer entered in response to the "writeln('How old are you ',name:length(name),'?');" statement around line 16.

It seems clear that the culprit is the "ch := readkey;" statement on line 18.
To enter a valid age, some key must first be pressed (other than  (ASCII 13) which is trapped by the "if ch = #13 then" statement.

It does not seem to matter if the "age" variable is typed as a string or integer.

What happens is that if one enters two characters or integers, only the second is stored in the "age" variable. For example, to input an age of "25", I must first press some other key on the keyboard first, then enter "25" for "25" to be stored in the "age" variable.

Any help understanding this would be sincerely appreciated. Perhaps the entire approach is incorrect?

```
PROGRAM t5;
uses crt;

var
  name,age  : string;
  ch        : char;

procedure greet;
  begin

    clrscr;
    writeln('What''s your name? ');
    readln(name);
    clrscr;
    writeln('Hi, ',name:length(name));
    writeln('How old are you ',name:length(name),'?');

    ch := readkey;
      if ch = #13 then
        begin
          writeln('Please enter a valid age!');
          writeln ('You pressed the ','"','Enter','"',' key ','("',ord(ch),'")');
          readln;
          writeln('Bye!');
          readln;
        end

      else if ch <> #13 then

        begin
          readln(age);
          writeln('Gee, ',age,', - that''s really old!');
          readln;
        end;
  end;


BEGIN

  greet;

END.
```

Comment: `Readkey` reads a **single** key.  So by including `ch := readkey`, your code will behave **exactly** as you describe, it will appear to ignore the first character of the user's age.

Answer (score 1):

`ReadKey()` reads one character (and removes it) from the keyboard buffer.

The problem is in this sequence:

```
ch := ReadKey; // the first digit is now in `ch`

if ch = #13 then  // this condition is false
  ...
else if ch <> #13 then // this condition is true
begin
  readln(age) // user types the second digit and <Enter>
  // then you use age, but you have omitted the first  character which is in `ch`
end;
```

Instead, use only `ReadLn()` and check that the returned characters are a proper number.

Comment: The thing which puzzles me a bit about the q is that the OP seems to understand what `readkey` does, but it then surprised when it does it!  But I suppose we've all been too close a a problem to see what it is, once in a while.

Comment: @MartynA I think OP did not know, or did not consider, that `ReadKey()` removes the character from the input buffer. I fully agree with you about occasionally not seeing our own errors.